# Jakarta EE modules used in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

Since Spring is an open source framework and its not implements and uses the full profile of the Jakarta EE 9 modules specifications, so please list me the implemented and used modules in Spring 6?

Dose Spring implement only the specs in the Core Profile or there is others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring does not fully embrace the Jakarta EE platform specification. Rather, it integrates with selected specifications from the traditional EE umbrella:

- WebSocket API (JSR 356)
- Concurrency Utilities (JSR 236)
- JSON Binding API (JSR 367)
- Bean Validation (JSR 303)
- JPA (JSR 338)
- JMS (JSR 914)
- Servlet API (JSR 340)
- Dependency Injection (JSR 330)
- Common Annotations(JSR 250)